# Metapost labels do not work with MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex, labels, metapost

I have upgraded from MiKTeX 2.8 to 2.9. All the label commands that earlier worked in Metapost are not working anymore. I am using MiKTeX in conjunction with TeXnicCenter. The MetaPost version apparently is 1.803 (MiKTeX 2.9). I am compiling the MP file separately using `mpost.exe`, the build process used for compiling MP files is highlighted below.

[image: The way mpost.exe is called from TeXnicCenter]

Example code for MP file is

```
beginfig(1);

draw (0,0)--(2cm,3cm);
draw thelabel.lft(btex $m$ etex,(0,0));

endfig;
end;
```

The output status from compilation is as follows:

```
--------------------Output Profile: Metapost--------------------
Metapost> This is MetaPost, version 1.803 (MiKTeX 2.9)
Metapost> (mpost.mp (C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/plain.mp
Metapost> Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004) )
Metapost> (C:/Vishnu/Miscellaneous/Metapost/Label problem/trial1.mp
```

Further each time compilation is carried out new files are created like `mp880129.tex`, `mp80530.tex` with the following content

```
\gdef\mpxshipout{\shipout\hbox\bgroup
\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}
\gdef\stopmpxshipout{\egroup  \dimen0=\ht0 \advance\dimen0\dp0
\dimen1=\ht0 \dimen2=\dp0
\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup
\box0
\ifnum\dimen0>0 \vrule width1sp height\dimen1 depth\dimen2 
\else \vrule width1sp height1sp depth0sp\relax
\fi\egroup
\ht0=0pt \dp0=0pt \box0 \egroup}
\mpxshipout% line 4 C:/Vishnu/Miscellaneous/Metapost/Label problem/trial1.mp
$m$%
\stopmpxshipout
\end{document}
```

I request some help to resolve this issue. I have been unable to find a solution for too long now.

Comment: Try `mpost --debug` and paste the result. Also, try to compile from command line `tex mp880129` and see if it works (it should generate a `.dvi` file)

Comment: The result generated using `mpost --debug` is as follows:

Comment: The result generated using `mpost --debug` is as follows:  `This is Metapost, version 1.803 (MiKTeX 2.9) (mpost.mp (C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/plain.mp   Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004))  (<working dir>/trial1.mpmakempx debug: <working dir>/trial1.mp: running command tex --parse-first-line --interaction=nonstopmode mp885472.tex makempx debug: C:/Vishnu/Miscellaneous/Metapost/Label problem/trial1.mp: 00203108 = fopen(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi10.tfm,"rb") [1]) ` The file still fails to compile properly.

Comment: Does the file `C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi10.tfm` exist? Can you successfully run `tex --parse-first-line --interaction=nonstopmode mp885472.tex`?

Comment: JLDiaz - Yes the file `C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi10.tfm` exists. I can also successfully run the above command, however only the letter _m_ (i.e. the label) is created in `mp885472.dvi` there is no sign of the line. The line isn't visible in resulting `fig.1` file.

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behaviour. Those temporal `.tex` files are created only to generate `.dvi`s which contain only the text. Then `dvitomp` extracts that text and leaves info in a `.mpx` file which is read back by mpost, and finally a `.1` file (which can be renamed to `.mps`) is created containing the lines and the labels. Your compilations fails when generating the `.dvi` still for unknown reasons. Try `mptopdf` instead of `mpost`.

Comment: Maybe it has nothing to do with it, but I heard that `tex` and `metapost` do not like spaces in file of folder names, and there is one here: `C:/Vishnu/Miscellaneous/Metapost/Label problem/trial1.mp`

Comment: I tried changing the folder names but to no avail. The problem with labels still persists.

Comment: Hi @JLDiaz I tried using `mptopdf` but it does not run, the message I get is `mptopdf.exe: The Perl interpreter could not be found.`

Comment: @Vishnu Sorry to hear that.. I didn't know that `mptopdf` required perl. Anyway, it was only a wild experiment, I expected indeed to cause the same problems than standard `mpost`, since it is also called internally by `mptopdf`, but who knows...

Comment: @JLDiaz Is there anyway I can get a solution to this problem? the problem clearly is with the commands `btex ... etex` phrase. `label` command otherwise works well atleast when I use it along with latex->dvi->ps->pdf to create PDF documents.

Comment: I have finally managed to work around the problem by completely uninstalling MiKTeX 2.9 and opting for TeX Live 2013 instead. It works perfectly now. It is so sad and unfortunate that with a 0.1 incremental change in version MiKTeX developers have chosen to completely ruin a working system. I have been using it for more than 8 years but I guess its time for me to move over to TeX Live if I wish to not make all my old files redundant. I could not resolve this problem in any other way, thanks @JLDiaz and others who helped me with their responses.

Comment: @Vishnu Good to know that you can resume your work. You can answer your own question with a short summary of the diagnosis and final solution, so we can remove these comments

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The solution of the problem is:

1. Start -> All Programs -> MikTex 2.9 -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Settings (Admin)
2. Select "Formats". The following window appears
   [image]
3. Click "New" and the following window appears
   [image]
4. Do the following

   (a) **Format key:** put whatever you want (for example, latex_metapost_btex)

   (b) **Format name:** latex

   (c) **Input file name:** latex.ini

   (d) **Output file name:** (*nothing, as it is*)

   (e) **Preloaded format:** (*nothing, as it is*)

   (f) **Description:** what you want

   (g) Uncheck "Exclude this format when updating all format files"

   (h) Click "OK"
5. In the previous window, select the line of the new format (for example, latex_metapost_btex) and click "Build", then click "OK"

Now the "btex etex" command works with a minor problem. Specifically, at the end of each label the symbol % is added. To solve the problem do the following:

- Put in the preamble of your code the command **\def\%{}**
- Of course, now you cannot use the symbol % for your labels. If you need to do this, put in the preamble of your code the command **\newcommand{\pct}{\char"25}** and use it for your labels.

Giorgos

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to work around the problem caused by MiKTeX 2.9. I have completely uninstalled MiKTeX 2.9 and installed TeX Live 2013 (I got the idea from Troy Henderson's webpage: http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/ which clearly states that it uses "*MetaPost  version 1.9 (TeX Live 2014/dev) (kpathsea version 6.2.0dev)*"). However, I still face problems trying to integrate it with TeXnicCenter. I still need to execute Metapost files from command line invoking the command `mpost filename.mp`. But the command line option works without any hitches. I am able to incorporate all labels without any problems.